# Get url of page (not yours) in a string

Tags: php, parsing, url

Wikipedia has a feature called Special:Random that when added to the end of "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" will direct to a random page.  For a website that I am making, I would like to be able to obtain a 'random' wikipedia article url, and after that, I can just parse the url to get the article name.  I don't want the url I receive in a string to have Special:Random in it but the article name.  Any ideas on how I may be able to implement this?

Comment: I realized I may not have understood your question thoroughly so I've moved it from answer to comment: "The URL resolves to the article title upon load, after which you can parse it"

Comment: So I guess could you clarify the use case? Are you saying you need to be able to accept "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" into **your** page and have it resolve to an article instead?

Comment: @AK4749 If I just parse the url as 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random' then I don't get the article name, just Special:Random though.

Comment: Ah yeah, got it. In that case you could "behind-the-scenes" make a request to Special:Random, and load the resulting resolved URL

Comment: @AK4749 I am trying to get the article name to be put into an input textbox.  When the user types in something and clicks enter, the text to appended to /wiki/.  I don't want the textbox to be populated with Special:Random, but rather an article name that is random if that helps!

Comment: alright, I'm starting to see what you're saying, but still a little confused. However, disregarding Special:Random for a moment, I think you just want a random, valid wikipedia article title, is that correct?

Comment: Thank you very much @AK4749!  This is my first experience with web programming so I'm not very good.  Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I have 0 experience in PHP, sorry, but look at http://php.net/manual/en/httprequest.send.php , and also take care to enable redirects as it mentions on that page. Once your HTTPRequest has been made, I'm sure you can look up the title/url/ whatever in the request's response data. Someone with actual PHP experience will be by shortly I'm sure to give you actual code